# How to change Bash to csh with username and password

Tags: linux, shell, csh

I want to change bash to `csh` I'm using following command which is not working 
`chsh -s /bin/csh insite(user) insite(password)`.

I need to write shell script with this command
this is the output i got

```
chsh -s /bin/csh insite insite 
Usage: chsh [ -s shell ] [ --list-shells ] [ --help ] [ --version ] [ username ]
```

Comment: What error message did you get? Why do you think that `chsh` takes a username and password as parameters?

Comment: [insite@T37 ~]$ chsh -s /bin/csh insite insite
Usage: chsh [ -s shell ] [ --list-shells ] [ --help ] [ --version ]
       [ username ]

Comment: Chsh command is taking Username(insite). after executing this command asking password. if i enter password manual its working. now i want to write this command in script. how can i enter password in script?

Comment: you'll likely need to use something like `expect` which can feed a password to `chsh`

Comment: @ avinash Kindly clarify whether you want to reset the password or you want to switch as insite at that time its asking password

Comment: is /bin/csh allowed ? does it appear in `chsh --list-shell` ?

Comment: by the way chsh would be enough to change your own shell.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this command is failing is because you are providing too many parameters. `chsh` does not accept a password on the command line, and if you are trying to change someone else's account you must be root:

```
sudo chsh -s /bin/csh insite
```

If you don't have `sudo`, become root by whatever means is appropriate to your situation and run

```
chsh -s /bin/csh insite
```

If you are trying to change your own shell you don't even need to be root - provided `/bin/csh` is listed in `/etc/shells`. You will have to enter your own password, though, to prove it is you who wants to change your shell.

```
chsh -s /bin/csh
Password: _
```